# how to group api in express

Tags: node.js, express

Here is the example:

```
var app = require('express')();

function validateToken(req, res, next) {
    // Do something with request here
    next();
};

app.get('/user/login', function(req, res) {
    //code
});

app.post('/user/register', function(req, res) {
    //code
})

app.put('/user/register', validateToken, function(req, res) {
    //code
})

app.delete('/user/delete', validateToken, function(req, res) {
    //code
})
```

If I have 10 api that need validToken, I should add validToken middleware 10 times, like:

```
app.method('......', validateToken, function(req, res) {
    //code
})

app.method('......', validateToken, function(req, res) {
    //code
})

....

app.method('......', validateToken, function(req, res) {
    //code
})

app.method('......', validateToken, function(req, res) {
    //code
})
```

How can I group api by using the same middleware?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to re-use the same callback function for multiple routes (like middleware):

```
var app = require('express')();

function validateToken(req, res, next) {
    // Do something with request here
    next();
};

app.get('/user/login', function(req, res) {
    // code
});

app.post('/user/register', function(req, res) {
    // code
});

// Be sure to specify the 'next' object when using more than one callback function.
app.put('/user/register', validateToken, function(req, res, next) {
    // code
    next();
});

app.delete('/user/delete', validateToken, function(req, res, next) {
    // code
    next();
});
```

Also, you can replace `app.METHOD` (e.g. `.post`, `.get`, `.put`, etc.) with `app.all` and your callback will be executed for any request type.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrong, so do not put into mass participation of the (Google translated from: 刚才看错了，改成这样就不用放进传参了)

```
var group = {url:true,url:true,url:true};
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if(group[req.url]){
        // Do something with request here
        next();
    } else {
        next();
    }
})
```

Comment: English only, please.

Comment: floor host is chinese. sorry